# Datagrid checkbox column that sends update mysql command

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've been reading a lot of answers on SO and I couldn't find a simple one to address my issue. I have a simple datagrid and I've added a checkbox column.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" x:Name="dtGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="false" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Audited"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MM-dd-yy}" Header="Date"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegularPaidHours}" Header="Regular Repair Hours"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My goal is to send an update command everytime a row is checked as audited. Somewhere along the lines of:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update MyTable set Location='" + Location + "',Date='" + Date + "',RegularPaidHours='" + RegularPaidHours + "', Audited '"yes" where ID = txt.id' , connection);
```

So if someone checks a rows, that row gets updated in the db. If not just have it null. Can someone please give me a helping hand with this? I don't really know what's my best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the column to a source property of your class where the `Location`, `Date` and `RegularPaidHours` property are already defined:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Audited" Binding="{Binding IsAudited, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

...and do whatever you want in the setter of the property:

```
private bool _isAuditing;
public bool IsAuditing
{
    get { return _isAuditing; }
    set
    {
        _isAuditing = value;
        //invoke a command or call a method that updates the DB from here...
        Task.Run(() => { UpdateDb(Location, ...) });
    }
}
```

> Can send the update command using sql in the code behind? I am looking to do it only with some code-behind.

Then you should replace the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and handle the `Checked` and `Unchecked` event for the `CheckBox` in the template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Audited" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Checked="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" Unchecked="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Unchecked"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsAudited, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Checked="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked" Unchecked="DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Unchecked"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsAudited, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

---

```
private void DataGridCheckBoxColumn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    var model = checkBox.DataContext as YourClass;

    //update the DB using the properties of your model...

}
```

Comment: I am not using MVVM or EF for this project. Can send the update command using sql in the code behind? Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? I am looking to do it only with some code-behind.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are using MVVM. You could still do whatever you want in the setter. But please refer to my edit.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for you clear explanation. I am grateful for you help! What shoud "YourClass" refer to? (checkBox.DataContext as YourClass;) Can you please offer a suggestion?

Comment: This is the type (class) of your DataObject where the Location, Date, ... properties are defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource lowCase}" x:Name="dtGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GridLinesVisibility="All" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="false" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Audited">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Command="{Here your command. Most Probably Relative Source Binding}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MM-dd-yy}" Header="Date"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegularPaidHours}" Header="Regular Repair Hours"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And Define corresponding RelayCommand with proper parameter in View Model

Comment: I am not using a View Model. How can I do it with some code-behind? Thanks.

Comment: Use MVVM its easy will save  you from future issues? For code behind you can directly work with DataGridRow Selected event